# Why does order matter in scanf command in C programming?

Tags: c, types, character, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int i;
    char x;
    float y;
    double z;

    //line1 
    printf("enter an integer");
    scanf("%d", &i);

    //line3
    printf("enter a character");
    scanf("%c", &x);

    printf("enter a floating point");
    scanf("%f", &y);

    printf("enter a double");
    scanf("%lf", &z);

    printf("Integer is %d \n character is %c \n floating point is %f \n double is %lf ",
           i, x, y, z);
}
```

My question is, when I run this code it doesn't prompt the input of a character value and skips to the next command. But if I swap line 3 with 1 i.e. if I prompt for character first and then integer, then it works fine. Please help me understand this problem.

Comment: Not what you're asking, but you may also want to add newlines at the end of your prompts or, if you don't want newlines, then explicitly `fflush()` stdout, otherwise you may run into output buffering preventing your prompts from appearing on the console.

Comment: So many duplicates!

Answer (score 2):

Most `scanf` format specifiers skip leading white-space (like newline), but `%c` does not (it should be able to read spaces).

That means the newline added to the input buffer from the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key you pressed for the previous input will be read by the `%c` format.

To skip leading space you need to add a space to the format string:

```
scanf(" %c",&x);
//     ^
// Note leading space here
```

Comment: Got it! It's working now... Thank you so much 

Answer (score 0):

Use the following format string in the call of `scanf` for an object of the type `char`.

```
scanf(" %c",&x);
      ^^^
```

Otherwise this call (without the leading blank) will read white space characters that for example correspond to the entered key Enter.